# Django admin login not working when creating new User structure

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-users

I am trying to create a new User model with 'AbstractBaseUser' and 'BaseUserManager' but for soemw reason now when creating a new super user, logging in does not work and shows this error:

> Please enter the correct email and password for a staff account. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive.

[Error Image here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FwRK.png)

Here is my code.

**models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
from django.db import models

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, firstName, lastName, phoneNumber, is_active=True, password=None, is_staff=False,
                    is_admin=False):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Users must have an email address.")
        if not password:
            raise ValueError("Users must have a password.")
        user_obj = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email)
        )
        user_obj.set_password(password)
        user_obj.save(using=self._db)
        user_obj.staff = is_staff
        user_obj.admin = is_admin
        user_obj.active = is_active
        return user_obj

    def create_staffuser(self, firstName, lastName, phoneNumber, email, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            firstName,
            lastName,
            phoneNumber,
            password=password,
            is_staff=True,
        )
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, firstName, lastName, phoneNumber, email, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            firstName,
            lastName,
            phoneNumber,
            password=password,
            is_staff=True,
            is_admin=True
        )
        return user



class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    objects = UserManager()

    firstName = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
    nickName = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
    phoneNumber = models.IntegerField(unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    confirmed_email = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    confirmed_phoneNumber = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    timeStamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)  # can login
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)  # staff; not superuser
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)  # superuser

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'  # username
    # email and password are required by default
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['firstName', 'lastName', 'phoneNumber']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.staff

    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        return self.admin

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return self.active

    def get_first_name(self):
        return self.firstName

    def get_last_name(self):
        return self.lastName

    def get_nick_name(self):
        return self.nickName

    def get_phone_number(self):
        return self.phoneNumber

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
```

**settings.py**

```
"""
Django settings for GSSO project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.1.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'There is a secret key here but I need to keep it secret, right.'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'api.User'

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'api',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'GSSO.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'GSSO.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

**GSSO\urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('api.urls')),
]
```

**api\urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework import routers

router = routers.DefaultRouter()


urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Comment: Why do you want to customize the Django default `first_name`, etc. to `firstName`? Since every other identifier in Django (and Python, the `logging` module notwithstanding) is in `snake_case`, mixing in `camelCase` sounds strange.

Comment: @AKX I guess I just prefer camel case also half way through coding it I realised I should have used snake_case but couldn't be bothered to go back and change it, It shouldn't matter right? Also, do you know why I am getting the error?

Comment: You'd just have that much an easier time if you derived from the Django `AbstractUser` class that already has `first_name`, `last_name` etc. instead of the `AbstractBaseUser`.

Comment: @AKX I am assuming you don't konw the answer then.

Comment: Not without looking more deeply into your code, which I am, sorry to say, not quite inclined to do since you seem to have needlessly customized things that don't quite need customizing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more info in order for the correct answer. for example, are you creating users through the default django admin panel? if so, what is the code in your `admin.py` file?

Also, have you registered your model using a UserAdmin or not? if not, there could be a problem with the password being hashed. When implementing a custom user, you need to register the user using something like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from .models import CustomUser

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
     pass
admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)
```